# Laravel blade is not working in jquery ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-blade

i want a url like this , http://localhost/myproject/get-dishes/1
here is my ajax request code

```
$('#MainDropDown').change(function(e){
               var cid = $(this).val();
               e.preventDefault();
              $.getJSON("{{url('get')}}/"+cid+" ", 

              function(data) {
                  var model = $('#dishDropDown');
                  model.empty();
                  $.each(data, function(index, element) {
                      model.append("<option value='"+element.id+"'>" + element.sub_cate_name + "</option>");
                  });
              });
  });

expected result:
```

http://localhost/teraso/public/get-dishes/1

showing:
http://localhost/teraso/public/add/%7%get-dishes/%D1

Answer (score 0):

Try another alternative way like route() or to() function.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
let url = "{{route('get',[':id-url'])}}";
url = url.replace(':id-url', $(this).val());
```

then, parse it to ajax

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
     var model = $('#dishDropDown');
     model.empty();
     $.each(data, function(index, element) {
           model.append("<option value='"+element.id+"'>" + element.sub_cate_name + "</option>");
     });
});
```